# Is mod_xsendfile deprecated?

Tags: apache-2.4

I know this is a stupid question, but I could not find the Information anywhere. I am maintaining a website for an old client and up until now I used the X-SENDFILE header to control the Access to a rather large file.

His Server administrators now updated Apache which broke the website. After doing some research I found out, that I had to remove the `XSendFileAllowAbove` Option and instead add `XSendFilePath`. Since this option apparently can not be set in the .htaccess file (I read about that, I also tried it to be sure) the server administrators have to add it directly. However, they refuse to do that and say that mod_xsendfile is deprecated. I searched to verify that but can not find it anywhere.

Also, they refuse to suggest an alternative, so if you guys know for any I¨d be thankful :).

The file is too large to be served with PHP (at least not easily), I have no access to the server, I can only access the website code.

### EDIT

As soon as I posted the question I found this post, which seems to at least suggest that mod_xsendfile is working perfectly well in Apache 2.4:
https://superuser.com/questions/1035459/is-mod-xsendfile-not-compatible-with-apache-2-4
This does not answer my question completely, but at least it's a start and may help someone searching for the same and finding this question.

Answer (score 4):

*Deprecated* here doesn't mean it won't work with Apache 2.4, but that it's against their own policy of quality software. After all, `mod_xsendfile`:

- is not a standard Apache module officially supported.
- needs to be compiled separately; not in any repository.
- was originally designed for Apache 2 & 2.2.
- hasn't been maintained since 2011; for 6 years.

Although the module is simple, using that kind of module may expose the system to security threats. Therefore, the limitation seems reasonable, and you definitely wouldn't get the module on any shared hosting, either.

Hopefully someone here can suggest alternative solutions!

Comment: `you definitely wouldn't get the module on any shared hosting, either.` - the shared webhosting of https://syse.no supported X-sendfile back when i used them (2018)

Comment: dreamhost.com shared webhosting supports X-sendfile today (2021-10-30)

Comment: https://www.interserver.net/ shared hosting also supports X-Sendfile

Answer (score 0):

the "latest" 1.0 version of x-sendfile works on apache 2.4. i just had to update all my servers to 1.0 from 0.6 after continuous dropped connections. the 1.0 version fixes the dropped connections problem.

https://github.com/nmaier/mod_xsendfile/blob/master/mod_xsendfile.c

Answer (score -4):

You can use the build-in directive so no need to the extra module

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#enablesendfile

Comment: The built in directive does not do the same thing as the old module.

Comment: @MichaelHampton what is the difference?

Comment: The built in directive applies only to static files. The old module uses sendfile at the direction of an upstream web application.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'm not sure if I get what you are trying to say. can you clarify what would be the practical difference?

Comment: Did you read the documentation of the module?

Comment: The module allows backend applications to use the `X-Sendfile` header to instruct Apache to return a static file. The built-in directive controls whether Apache uses the `sendfile` Linux system call to transmit file data to a client for static files. Completely different thing.